# Right way to handle input in critical applications?

Tags: microcontroller, safety

could someone please explain what would be propper way to handle user button on critical system like operator remote controller. Are there any documents related to safety when buttons are concern.

In our case we have two options which were discussed:

1. Have max debouncer chip connected to uC and handle inside interrupt.
2. Have the button connected to pin , do software debouncing and handling of button presses in polling inside while.

Comment: What does "critical application" mean? Every business (medical, automotive, aerospace, ...) has its own standards and regulations. Regarding your option 1: What if - for some reason (EMI?) - you get a spike on your µC input? You can't rely on just one interrupt signal, even if debouncing itself may be ok.

Comment: What safety requirements are you trying to fulfill? Debouncing is rarely a safety concern: if hitting a button in a rapid succession is dangerous, you will have safety issues even if debouncing works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Usually safety critical switching requires more then one input.

Typically you either have two inputs per switch wired to sense opposite conditions and logic to go to fail to a safe state if the appropriate conditions are not met, or something like using an analogue input pin with a chain of three resistors such that short, open, switch open and switch closed can be detected as distinct states (If you are really paranoid you can have two of these things with opposite contact states and different potential divider strings .

Your choice of external or internal debounce is a side issue, but I would be very careful about interrupts in a SIL 3 or 4 project, they are hard to justify, especially when driven from an external pin because they make the state machine that is the processor very hard to reason about (And a complete nightmare to debug). Personally I like a polled input, with a simple software timer for debounce, a chip that is not on the board cannot have a dry joint.

I would note also that the design of buttons themselves for safety critical applications has been studied, NASA did an extensive study on the design and ergonomics of the switch that commands the destruction of a rocket at the range safety officer position, it is interesting.

Comment: Got a link to the NASA thing? :)  You can't leave us in suspenders like that.

Comment: Turns out NASA are buggers for not leaving things where they put them... My link is broken, but a quick search turns up a LOT of stuff on safety critical design from them, but not easily the Apollo era document I remember (The modern stuff suffers from a serious fascination with powerpoint).

Comment: does sil specs say anything about using interrupt as not acceptable?

Comment: @DanMills... "Turns out NASA are buggers for not leaving things where they put them..." all apart from lunar rovers and flags :)

Comment: I don't have access to the standards at the moment (and they keep being revised), but I am fairly sure MISRA at least warns and requires justification for using them. It also used to be the case that interrupts were banned in railway signalling applications over here, but I don't know the current state of play of that one.